# Trying to Use Tka11y

Tags: tkinter, accessible

I am working on creating an application that helps the visually impaired learn coding. I resorted to using TKinter(), however, the screenreader would not read the values in the GUI out.

I learned that Tka11y helps TKinter become more accessible by enabling screen-readers to do so. Apparently it's supposed to have the same old functions as TKinter plus new ones so I wrote:

import Tka11y as Tkinter.

However, when I wrote Tkinter.Tk(), it's telling me that there is no such function called Tkinter.Tk().

The API on TKinter isn't too helpful either unfortunately.